# PDFlib library PHP background image

Tags: php, background, pdflib

I'm using PDFlib library PHP to write PDF.

Can I put an image as a background for a whole page? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: i tried several ways to put a background image.

Comment: @JamWaffles i used the code which was in php manual.
<?php
$pdf = PDF_new();
PDF_open_file($pdf,'');
PDF_begin_page($pdf,595,842);
$image = PDF_load_image($pdf,"png","myimage.png","");
PDF_place_image($pdf,$image,64,26,.24);
?>
but no luck.it came up with Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDFlibException' with message 'Handle parameter 'image' has bad value 0' in C:\xampp\htdocs\istore\pdf_image.php:57 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\istore\pdf_image.php(57): pdf_place_image() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\istore\pdf_image.php on line 57
then i tried to solve that problem.but i coudn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you should do something like this:

```
$image = $p->load_image("auto", $imagefile, "");
if ($image == 0) {
    die("Error: " .  $p->get_errmsg());
}
$p->begin_page_ext(0, 0, "width=595 height=842");
$p->fit_image($image 0, 0, "boxsize { 595 842} fitmethod=entire");
```

If you do this before placing the text in the PDF you will get it as background image.

You may have a look at http://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/images/ for more image related examples and check chapter 7.3 in the documentation "PDFlib-tutorial.pdf".